# Homebrew claims it's outdated, except when I try to update

Tags: macos, homebrew

When I run `brew doctor` I'm told that my brew installation is outdated. Specifically:

```
~$ brew doctor
Error: Your Homebrew is outdated
You haven't updated for at least 24 hours, this is a long time in brewland!
```

But when I run update, apparently, all is fine:

```
~$: brew update
Already up-to-date.
```

So, I guess all is good? Not so much. `brew doctor` still tells me my Homebrew is outdated. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is good. It's just a bad way of communicating it.

The Homebrew `doctor` source clearly [only checks for the timestamp](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/cmd/doctor.rb#L844) of your Homebrew repository clone:

```
if Time.now.to_i - timestamp > 60 * 60 * 24 then <<-EOS.undent
  Your Homebrew is outdated
  You haven't updated for at least 24 hours, this is a long time in brewland!
  EOS
end
```

It doesn't have any clue about when you really updated or whether there's even a new version available.